# Cleartext content routing header in WCF with netTcp and Transport security

Tags: wcf, header, nettcpbinding

The traffic flow for my application is 1) .Net client to 2) F5 BigIP load balancer VIP to 3) .Net WCF service node. The WCF service is using the netTcp binding with the security mode set to Transport and a Transport protectionLevel of EncryptAndSign. I need to provide the load balancer with a value it can use to route the request to a specific WCF service node. The value is dependent on the user making the request and obviously it has to be cleartext for the load balancer to read it. Is such a thing - wrapping an encrypted netTcp tarnsport payload with a cleartext header value - possible in stock WCF? If not, is there something custom I could write to do it?